# Set Rails 5 custom URL using two parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I currently have this setup and it works fine as I get the `first_name` in the URL as desired:

```
resources :pilots, param: first_name, constraints: { first_name: /.*/ }

 def to_param
    first_name
  end
```

How can I do this with two parameters - so a `first_name` and a `last_name` in the URL?

Comment: I don't think you can achieve this with the resources macro as its way off  from the intended use case which is generating RESTful resource URLs. You can do it manually with `get "/pilots/:last_name/:first_name", to: "pilots#show"` but I would consider if its really a worthwhile feature.

Answer (score 0):

A decent and common option would be to use [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id)

After adding the gem, you could add the following in your model (basic setup) :

```
extend FriendlyId
friendly_id :slug
def slug
  "#{first_name} from #{last_name}"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out...

```
class Pilot < ApplicationRecord

    before_validation :fullname  

def fullname
    self.full_name = "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
  end

end
```

Routes:

```
resources :pilots, param: :full_name
```

Pilot Controller:

```
before_action :set_pilot, only: [:show]

def set_pilot
        @artist = Artist.find_by(full_name: params[:full_name])
    end
```